# How to delete data from clipboard in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a JavaScript function which is used for copytoclipboard and is working fine in IE8.
but the problem is after pasting i want to delete old copied data and copy paste new data.
How to delete old copied data from clipboard and copy new data using javascript,jquery

Comment: If the user is supposed to paste in the same application, you can guess that he pasted, by capturing Ctrl-v presses. A robust solution would be hard or impossible to achieve.